# Find the Integrating Factor of $xdy-3ydx=\frac{x^4}{y}dy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is integrating factor by inspection, $xdy-3ydx=\frac{x^4}{y}dy$ I've been trying to look for the Integrating factor for this problem but I can't still get one right. I think I really need to use the $3ydx$ in the problem since it has the $dx$ but i can't remove the $-3$ any ideas how?

Comment: This is a non-linear problem, you're probably best off making substitutions instead.

Comment: @Mattos can you give me a hint on how should i approach this problem? I don't clearly understand what you meant by subsitutions. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I left the computer and didn't see your comment. It seems like you have two very good answers anyway.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

As Mattos commented, considering the terms of the equation written as $$xy'-3y=\frac{x^4}{y}y'$$ a (may be) good idea would to start defining $y=x^3z$ which, after simplifications, leads to $$\frac{x (z-1) z'}{z}=3$$ which is now separable and easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$xdy-3ydx=\frac{x^4}{y}dy$$ $$xdy-\frac{x^4}{y}dy-3ydx=0$$ $$\left(x-\frac{x^4}{y}\right)dy-3ydx=0$$ $$\left(\frac{xy-x^4}{y}\right)-3y\frac{dx}{dy}=0$$ $$\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{1}{3y}\left(\frac{xy-x^4}{y}\right)=0$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{x}{3y}+\frac{x^4}{3y^2}=0$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{x}{3y}=-\frac{x^4}{3y^2}$$
It is clear that above equation is the form: $\frac{dx}{dy}+P(y)x=Q(y)x^n$

Hence, integration factor (I.F.) is given as  $$I.F.=e^{\int \frac{-1}{3y}dy}$$$$=e^{-\frac{1}{3}\int \frac{dy}{y}}$$  $$=e^{-\frac{1}{3}\ln y}$$ $$=e^{\ln (y)^{-1/3}}=(y)^{-1/3}$$$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{y}}$$

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{I.F.=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{y}}}}$$